# No R, quando um vetor se torna "too long"?

Tags: r, array, memória

Ao tentar criar um vetor infinito (`1:Inf`) recebi a seguinte mensagem:

> Error in 1:Inf : result would be too long a vector

Contudo, quando o vetor não sabe na memória a mensagem costuma ser diferente. O código abaixo criar as três situações: a) consegue criar o vetor, b) não cabe na memória e c) "too long".

```
object.size(1:1e9) # limite superior do tipo a
# 4000000040 bytes

object.size(1:1e10) # limite inferior do tipo b
# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 74.5 Gb

...

object.size(1:1e15) # limite superior do tipo b
# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7450580.6 Gb

object.size(1:1e16) # limite inferior do tipo c
# Error in 1:1e+16 : result would be too long a vector
```

Pergunta: dado que os dois vetores (tipo b e tipo c) não caberiam na memória, como o `R` define que ele caia em um caso ou no outro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso tem a ver com o código fonte do R. Veja que a função `:` está definida em C [aqui](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/seq.c#L97). Lá, você pode encontrar que esse erro aparece nessa condição:

```
 double r = fabs(n2 - n1);
 if(r >= R_XLEN_T_MAX)
     errorcall(call, _("result would be too long a vector"));
```

Essa constante `R_XLEN_T_MAX` por sua vez é definida [aqui](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bf0a0a9d12f2ce5d66673dc32cd253524f3270bf/src/include/Rinternals.h#L74).

```
# define R_XLEN_T_MAX 4503599627370496
```

Ou seja, se o número for maior que `4503599627370496`, acontecerá o erro.
Agora veja que:

```
> 4503599627370496 > 1e15
[1] TRUE
> 4503599627370496 > 1e16
[1] FALSE
```

Veja também isso aqui:

```
> k <- 1:4503599627370496
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 33554432.0 Gb
> k <- 1:4503599627370497
Error in 1:4503599627370497 : result would be too long a vector
```

Comment: Será que este número tem algum motivo de ser?

Comment: @TomásBarcellos  Aí eu já não sei... Até tentei procurar, ams não achei... Ele é 2^52...